# Consuming web api in XML format without root element

Tags: xml

Web API returns result in XML format.
This is the format

`<A><a>..</a><b>..</b></A>
<A><a>...</a><b>..</b></A>`

Is this the right format? There is no root element in the XML.
Error when i consume the API : Data at root element is invalid.

Edit:

I have come to know that the above XML format is incorrect. So I want to manually append the root element to the XML. Here is the code:

```
try
 {
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
         var url = "URL";
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders
         .Accept
         .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
         var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
         HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
         var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
         str.Append("<district>"); //manually adding root element
         str.Append(content);
         str.Append("</district>");//manually adding root element
         var res = str;
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
         doc.LoadXml(res.ToString());
         string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
//just ignore this line. It is Xamarin code
         //list.ItemsSource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AClass>>(jsonText);
      }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

However, after **manually adding the root element**, the XML becomes something like this

```
<districts>"<A><a>...</a><b>...</b></A><A><a>...</a><b>...</b></A>"</districts>
```

This is what I want:

```
"<districts><A><a>...</a><b>...</b></A><A><a>...</a><b>...</b></A></districts>"
```

[Look at the double quotes!]
Any Idea? Thanks!

Comment: I see this is an invalid XML. So how to add root element to xml web api which is deployed on server?

Comment: It's invalid, but if you can't change what is sending the result.  Then just in whatever is consuming this, append a node like `<root> + string + </root>` before trying to convert to xml.  If you want a more specific answer, I need to know what code and language is consuming this xml

Comment: I an using C#. Currently it is <root>"string"</root>. i want "<root>string</root>"

Comment: Please edit your question to contain this information.  Include a sample of your code showing how you tried to solve the problem.  I'm not much of a C# developer so I will probably have to defer to others.

Comment: @TrevorD, I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, just substring.  I can't remember the C# format exactly, but basically  `str.Append(content.substring(1,content.length-2));` to grab everything except the first letter, and everything except the last letter. If your not sure it will always have the quotes, check the beginning and end of the string for chr(34) first.